# how to detect form feild change live to show or hide submit button

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

MY form look like below:

```
<form id="myform">
    <fieldset>
        <div class="row-fluid">
            <label class="checkbox"><input type="checkbox" id="status" name="status">Active</label>
        </div>
        <div class="row-fluid">
            <label>Address</label>
            <input type="text" id="city" name="city" />
            <input type="text" id="state" name="state" />
        </div>
        <a id="save" class="btn btn-primary hide">save changes</a>
        <a id="close" class="btn">Close</a>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

My this form appear pre-populated. That is my status is checked, name has value Anyname, city has value Anycity, and State has value AnyState. Basically, the save changes form is hidden when the form appears. But, if user click on any of the field, just append any character or remove character, it should detect the changes live any immediately set save changes button to show i.e. remove class hide. If again, the appended character is removed and set to original, it should again hide the save change button.

Basically it is to detect form field change live and hide or show button live.

I had look at couple of  question related to it but none of them fulfilled my requirement.

I tried

```
 $('myform:input, myform:checkbox').change(function() {
      $("#save").removeClass("hide");
});
```

Comment: You should mention that you're using BackBone.js, as what you need is probably very easily achieved using functionality within the library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<strike>Since you need to compare the original value against the current value, you'd have to store the original values somewhere.</strike>

As pointed out in the comments by CBroe, you can get the original values of each element using `defaultValue` or `defaultChecked`:

The following checks each input to see whether or not the value has changed, and returns the `length` (number) of elements which have. You can then use that to show/hide the save button.

```
var $inputs = $('#myform :input');
$inputs.on('keyup change', function() {

  var dataChanged = $inputs.filter(function() {
    if ($(this).is(':checkbox')) {
      var originalValue = this.defaultChecked;
      var currentValue = this.checked;
    } else {
      var originalValue = this.defaultValue;
      var currentValue = this.value;
    }
    return originalValue != currentValue;
  }).length;    

  if (dataChanged == 0) {
    $('#save').addClass('hide') 
  } else { 
    $('#save').removeClass('hide');
  }

});
```

Notice how I've attached the `keyup()` event as well as the `change()` event. This will trigger the function for the text inputs when a key is pressed, and hide or show the save button immediately.

#### [Here's a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qaf4M/2/)

Comment: A few minor points: 1. Initialise the variables using the `var` keyword so you don't pollute the global scope with unnecessary global variables. 2. `originalValue` makes no sense as the variable name; it's not the original value, it's the current one. 3. You can use `this.checked` to get the current checked state of the input if it's a checkbox, you don't need to use `$this.prop('checked')` (saves you some function calls).

Comment: That doesn't quite cut it - if you change either of the values back to the original then the Save button is removed, even if the other values have changed.  It sounds like it should be straight forward as there's already a BackBone model for the values - I've never used BB but I'm guessing dirty checking will be included.

Comment: yes it does work clearly in js fiddle. But, when i include it inside backbone view, its not working.  I guess this is here local. I have also this for view.

Comment: i checked $('#myform :input').on('keyup change', function() {
             alert(1);
         }); , it alerts well on value change

Comment: _“you'd have to store the original values somewhere”_ – they already are, in the `defaultValue` property every form element possesses (resp. `defaultChecked` for checkboxes/radiobuttons).

Comment: Everyone has great answer here. Thanks to community power. I would like to accept this answer for this meet more my requirements.

Comment: @lasang: As you're using Backbone, can't you just bind the visibility of the Save button to the `changed` property of your model? I don't know much about Backbone, but that's the way I'd expect it to work based on other MVx frameworks I've used.

Comment: yes, I am thinking to do in that way. I want backbone model that populate my form to bind to change event. But, I am too new and will update answer after I get it done

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [this working jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tUAeh/4/)

```
$('input', '#myform').keyup(function() {
     if ( $(this).val() !=  $(this).attr('value') ){
          $("#save").removeClass("hide");
     }else{
         donthide = false;
         $('input', '#myform').each(function(){
             console.log($(this).val() + ' ?= ' + $(this).attr('value'));
             if ( $(this).val() != $(this).attr('value') ){
                 donthide = true;
             }
         });
         console.log(donthide);
         if (!donthide) $('#save').addClass('hide');
     }
});
```

This will only work if all of the fields have a 'value' attribute, but you could alter it to compensate for a missing value.

Answer (score 1):

You're referring to an element with an ID of `accept`, but that doesn't exist in your HTML.

Your save button has an ID of `save`.

Here's a jsfiddle which shows the button when the values are changed: http://jsfiddle.net/Town/tUAeh/

In order to hide the button when the fields are returned to their previous values, you'll need to store the initial value and compare it to the current in order to work out whether or not a change has actually occurred.

It's also worth noting that the `change` event only fires on a text box when focus is lost.  I'm not sure if that's a problem for you or not, but you may be better to use `keyup` for that.

Comment: In your jsFiddle, you listen for `change()` on 'input' and 'checkbox', but checkbox isn't an element, it is also an inpout element ;)

Comment: your code nearly works. But, I have some pre-populated value. that is address has some value intially. Example state : newyork . Now, if i just make newyorks, jst append one s , it should immedaitely show save cahnges button before i make "newyorkss" two ss appended. And if i make it back it newyork again, it should hide the button again.

Comment: @Lasang How do you put in the pre-populated value? is it like `<input type="text" value="newyork" />`?

Comment: @Lasang: what you're describing there is what I've mentioned at the end of the answer - the `change` event only fires when focus is lost, not as each character changes. You'll want `keyup` for that.  In order to compare the current to the original value, you'll need some more code (which I've also mentioned in the answer).

Comment: @Billy Mathews , actually my form is template and I populate  them with some backbone model. So, I am trying to make it like twitter profile tab edit . If form get value from model. So, if i click on any of them and try to edit, I am trying to detect immediately and show button to save. Again, if backslash or by anyway make value to original value, it should again hide shown save button.

Answer (score 1):

First you have to save the current values, then compare when any change takes place.  I use the .data to store the original.

EDIT: removed some debug/show action code from the original.

```
// save original values
$(':input').each(function () {
    var setvalue = getCurrentValue($(this));
    $(this).data('originalvalue', setvalue);
});
// check them if anything changes
$(':input').change(function () {
    if (checkvalues()) {
        $("#save").addClass("hide");
    } else {
        $("#save").removeClass("hide");
    }
});
//return current value for checking/setting
function getCurrentValue(checkMe) {
    var currentValue = '';
    if (checkMe.is(':checkbox')) {
        currentValue = checkMe.prop('checked');
    } else {
        currentValue = checkMe.val();
    }
    return currentValue;
}
// if any do not match original, return false
function checkvalues() {
    var original = true;
    $(':input').each(function () {
        var currentValue = getCurrentValue($(this));
        var originalValue = $(this).data('originalvalue');
        if (currentValue !== originalValue) {
            original = false;
        }
    });
    return original;
}
```

EDIT: a bit more compact version of the above:

```
$(':input').each(function () {
    $(this).data('originalvalue', getCurrentValue($(this)));
});
$('#myform').on('change', ':input', function () {
    if (checkvalues()) {
        $("#save").addClass("hide");
    } else {
        $("#save").removeClass("hide");
    }
});

function getCurrentValue(checkMe) {
    return checkMe.is(':checkbox') ? checkMe.prop('checked') : checkMe.val();
}

function checkvalues() {
    var original = true;
    $(':input').each(function () {
        if (getCurrentValue($(this)) !== $(this).data('originalvalue')) {
            original = false;
        }
    });
    return original;
}
```

Example of compact version in action:  http://jsfiddle.net/gRXDN/

Answer (score 0):

Did it give you an error? Because it should do, since you are missing a quote after #accept.
And I think your selector is weird, try

```
$('#myform input[type=text], #myform [type=checkbox]').change();
```

Since there is no element called myform in which state is :input

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
$('input[type=text] input[type=checkbox]').change(function(){
    $('#save').removeClass('hide'); 
});
```

In form no "accept" id.Make sure do you removeclass to accept id.